# Vue 3: make depended props of other props in one component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to make a component whose props will directly depend on each other.

Usage 1 (when `variant="first"` I must set `height`, `width` must be not available):

```
<Example variant="first" :height="100" />
```

Usage 2 (when `variant="second"` I must set `width`, `height` must be not available):

```
<Example variant="second" :width="100" />
```

Code of `Example` component:

```
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        variant: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            validator: function(value) {
                // The value must match one of these strings
               return ['first', 'second'].indexOf(value) !== -1
            }
        },
        height: {
            type: Number,
            required: true // <-- Only when variant is "first"
        },
        width: {
            type: Number,
            required: true // <-- Only when variant is "second"
        }
    }
}
```

Example from **React**:

```
const Example = (
    props:
        { variant: "First"; height: number } |
        { variant: "Second"; width: number }
    ) => {
    /*...code...*/
};
```

**How to do this in Vue 3 + TypeScript?**

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the `validator` function available for props.

[docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-data.html#props)

> `validator`: Function Custom validator function that takes the prop value as the sole argument. In a non-production environment, a console warning will be thrown if this function returns a falsy value (i.e. the validation fails).

alternatively, you could add custom validation either through a lifecycle hook like `mounted` or using a `watch`. The lifecycle method is *OK* if you know the prop values are not changing, if they are not static, then use a `watch` which is a more reliable solution.

Comment: none of the described solutions will provide the correct typescript validation at compile time :(